# Typescript Type Located In Node Module Doesn't Appear To Work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Using the material-ui@next library and typescript in a React project, 
here is my code

```
   <CardMedia   image={item.image_url} style={{ width: 238, height: 124.5 }}
    />
```

I'm getting the error

```
(54,19): error TS2339: Property 'image' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<CardMedia> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> &...'.
```

CardMedia has an image prop https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/demos/cards/#media

The interface has an image prop https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/Card/CardMedia.d.ts (I’ve checked. It exists in my local node modules)

What could be causing an issue like this? Is there something wrong with my config?

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce this. Please make sure you have the right versions of packages.

1) Latest material-ui. 1.0.0-beta.13 work for me.

2) Either @types/react 15.6.0 or latest @types/react 16.0.7 works.

3) Latest typescript - 2.5.3.

Also please check if you import CardMedia correctly like so

`import {CardMedia} from "material-ui";`